# Trigger event when a particular text fragment shows up in Find? (ctrl-F)

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

When the user searches for text within a page (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>), does it trigger any Javascript-accessible events?

**Here's my example use case:**

- I have an information-dense documentation page where the primary sections are listed in a sidebar.
- These primary sections expand to show sub-headings (hidden until user views that section).
- Sub-sections can be difficult to find, unless you've been deep-linked to the page.
- It'd be nice to piggyback on browser "find" functionality, so that if the user searches for some buried item, the JS will detect it and reveal that section.

Please disregard the UX assumptions here. This could also be easily accomplished with a custom search field that exists on the page. I'm only curious about the technical feasibility of detecting (and piggybacking upon) the built-in browser find functionality.